Webcomic involving office politics and a virtual reality plane dogfighting game
I could have sworn that I read this on the Giant in the Playground, probably best known for Order of the Stick and, to a lesser degree, Erfworld. If so, I don't know if it was a Rich Burlew, Rob Balder, or other author. It was a fairly self-contained story that began and ended. The game might have been the main product of the company? The protagonist is a nebbish employee, maybe a programmer. He has someone in the office that he's interested in, but there's a love triangle with a loutish (and I think more athletic) male co-worker who's also interested in her. Somehow, it all comes down to a contest in this dogfighting game, which he ekes out a win due to superior tactics. I don't remember anything underhanded going on. My memory of the ending was that he had proven himself to the girl, but it stopped short of an "I have won you" scenario, but more that he had a chance now.
I am pretty sure that I read it over 5-6 years ago, and it might have been a good decade or so earlier. My online searches haven't turned up much so far, largely indicating that Order of the Stick and Erfworld were comics on the site.
And, writing it all out, I'm not 100% certain if it actually was virtual reality, or if it was a matter of the protagonist having imagined the action of the competition (maybe with a side of his success in part being due to his vivid imagination making him more invested in it). I think that it was entirely in a comic book format rather than the occasional illustrated text that became common for Erfworld, Poppy O'Possum, or Paranatural.
